# SQL Query based on other table

Tags: mysql

I have a normalized table:

```
`Table: TheMovies`
id      | MovieName 
---------------------
1       | Zootopia 
2       | Moana 
3       | Toy Story

`Table: TheGenres`
id      | GenreName 
---------------------
21      | Action 
22      | Animation 
23      | Adventure

`Table: mMoviesGenres`
movieID | genreID 
---------------------
1       | 21 
1       | 23 
2       | 22
2       | 21 
3       | 23
3       | 21
```

All works fine, but I need a query which will show me similar movies in same genres (in our case we need similar movies for MovieID = 1 which should output MovieID = 3 as result).

Can you give me an SQL query so I have a basic idea of doing that, to be able to create more advanced queries?

My query, so far, is:

```
SELECT 
    TheMovies.* 
FROM 
    mMoviesGenres 
        JOIN TheMovies ON mMoviesGenres.movieID = TheMovies.id 
WHERE 
    mMoviesGenres.genreID IN 
        (
            SELECT 
                genreID 
            FROM 
                mMoviesGenres 
            WHERE 
                movieID = 1
        )
```

** In my Opinion, the Table: TheMovies is not needed to do what I ask for

Comment: Is this MySQL or SQL Server? Also, what have you tried already? What, exactly, are you stuck on?

Comment: I tried this: SELECT TheMovies.* FROM mMoviesGenres 
 JOIN TheMovies ON mMoviesGenres.movieID = TheMovies.id
 WHERE mMoviesGenres.genreID 
 IN (SELECT genreID FROM mMoviesGenres WHERE movieID = 1

Comment: Still the question mysql or sql?

Comment: The language is Mysql

Comment: Shouldnt it also return movieID 2? It has just one more genre which dont means its a different type of movie to me!?

Comment: @PHPLover I've removed the SQL Server tag and added your query to question.  As a general rule it is best to edit the question, rather that add to the comments.  Why?  Because it is easier to follow if all the important information is in one place.

Comment: @C4u, yes it should because it contains both 21 and 23, I just changed it to make the example more understandable.

Comment: @Destination-data thanks for editing for me ;)

Comment: Is this impossible in MySQL?

Comment: This is very possible in MySQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT m2.movieId
FROM mMoviesGenres m1
INNER JOIN mMoviesGenres m2
    ON m1.genreID = m2.genreID
WHERE m1.movieId = 1 AND
      m2.movieId <> 1
GROUP BY m2.movieId
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mMoviesGenres WHERE movieId = 1)
```

**Update:**

If you want to find movies which are similar with regard to at least two genres, then use this `HAVING` clause:

```
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2
```

Comment: Can this be mate without using the MovieName, and instead the ID?

Comment: this does not check if all genres match with other movies

Comment: @PHPLover I have updated my answer, please try again.

Comment: I am recieving the following error:You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'm2.movieId <> 1
GROUP BY (m2.movieId)
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mM' at line 6

Comment: @PHPLover Simple typo, try again

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'm2.movieID <> 1
GROUP BY m2.movieID
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mMov' at line 6

Comment: Missing `AND` in the `WHERE` clause, sorry.

Comment: Wow!!! This query is magic, finally I got it. Thanks @TimBiegeleisen, just one more question, can I use this code you've built to find similiar movies based just on 2 genres instead of all? Or a total reconstruction of the query is needed?

Comment: This query will fail for those movies which have same genre but have an additional genre..., is there any way to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT M.id FROM TheMovies M 
LEFT JOIN mMoviesGenres MG ON M.id = MG.movieID 
LEFT JOIN TheGenres G ON MG.genreID = G.id
```

You are in the correct vicinity with your attempt, but you got it somewhat in the wrong order. Start with TheMovies as it contains the ID you are after. Then add in mMoviesGenres as it is the link between the two tables you are trying to match. And lastly add in the Genres, which will be able to check which movies that are related.

Comment: This works , but it just displays all movies, what I need is that only movies which match all genres will be displayed. So if I search for similiar movies for MovieID = 1 then only movies with: Action & Adventure both will be displayed