# Laravel orderBy whereHas

Tags: php, laravel

This question is related to: [Laravel (5.3) Eloquent - Relationship issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41123931/laravel-5-3-eloquent-relationship-issue), please access this url for more information.

I ended up with the following script:

```
$genres = ['action', 'drama', 'romance'];

$similiarSeries = TheSeries::whereHas('TheGenres', function($q) use($genres) {
        $q->whereIn('genre', $genres);
}, '>=', 1);

return $similiarSeries->take(10);
```

What it does is: It checks for movies which has at least 1 genre from above variable, and returns 10 movies (if exist).

The problem is that they movies are being returned in a chaotic order, instead I would preffer if they would be displayed giving priority to the movies which are: action, drama, romance and then return those movies with only 2 genres (like: drama, romance or romance, action). and then only 1 genre.

Is this possible in laravel?

## UPDATE

This is an example list of movies and their genres:

```
Zootopia: Action, Animation, Drama
Toy Story: Action, Drama, Romance
Kung Fu Panda: Action, Animation, Fantasy
Avatar: Action, Drama, Romance
Titanic: Action, Drama, Romance
Avengers: Fantasy, Drama, Fiction
Batman: Adventure
```

So if we search movies which have at least one of ['action','drama','romance'],

I am expecting the following to be returned:

```
Toy Story (Action, Drama, Romance) (3)
Avatar (Action, Drama, Romance) (3)
Titanic (Action, Drama, Romance) (3)
Zootopia (Action, Drama) (2)
Kung Fu Panda (Action) (1)
Avengers (Drama) (1)
Batman (0)
```

Comment: Try to give another example please. WIth real movie names and genre names. What do you have, and what do you need to be returned.

Comment: #ArturSubotkevic just updated the question.

Comment: With the 0 genres too? What the?

Comment: @ArturSubotkevic Yes, in case there is less then 10 movies, the space needs to be filled up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, got you.

As of Laravel 5.2.41 you can use `withCount()` method like this:

```
$similiarSeries = TheSeries::whereHas('TheGenres', function($q) use($genres) {
    $q->whereIn('genre', $genres);
})->withCount(['TheGenres' => function ($query) use ($genres) {
    $query->whereIn('genre', $genres);
}])->orderBy('TheGenres_count', 'desc');

return $similiarSeries->take(10);
```

This will order by matched genres count (desc).

Comment: I just checked it, there is a problem, this counts the number of genres a particular series has not actually what I need.

Comment: Wait... So what count do you need? :D

Comment: I need it to sort by genres which are part of the array given.

Comment: Check my example again, you've understood it wrong.

Comment: Your example will display the movies with 5 genres first, instead I need to display the movies which has max number of genres as in array provided.