# Laravel PHP orderBy WhereHas count Child

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following code:

```
  $genres = ['action', 'drama', 'romance'];
  $similiarSeries = TheEpisode::with('TheSeries.TheGenres')->whereHas('TheSeries.TheGenres', function($q) use($genres) {
      $q->whereIn('genre', $genres);
  });
```

This code will:
1. Make TheGenres visible (relationship)
2. Will search for TV series with Genres of Action or Drama or Romance.

But now I would like that those will be sorted depending on the number of matches with the `$genres` array.

Let's say `TheEpisode` with `TheSeries.TheGenres` matches all 3 genres (action, drama, romance), those should be ordered first, then another `TheEpisode` matches only 2 genres (action, drama), this should be ordered as second...

This question is very related to [Laravel orderBy whereHas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41173698/laravel-orderby-wherehas).

```
$similiarSeries = TheSeries::whereHas('TheGenres', function($q) use($genres) {
    $q->whereIn('genre', $genres);
})->withCount(['TheGenres' => function ($query) use ($genres) {
    $query->whereIn('genre', $genres);
}])->orderBy('TheGenres_count', 'desc');

return $similiarSeries->take(10);
```

The only difference is that now we are trying to fetch `TheEpisode` which is related to `TheSeries`.

## UPDATE

I've tried the following code, which should work in my oppinion, but it says that property "TheGenres" is undefined:

```
  $similiarSeries = TheEpisode::with('TheSeries.TheGenres')->whereHas('TheSeries.TheGenres', function($q) use($genres) {
      $q->whereIn('genre', $genres);
  })->withCount(['TheSeries' => function ($q) use ($genres) {

      $q->TheGenres->whereIn('genre', $genres);
  }])->orderBy('the_genres_count', 'desc');
```

Is this impossible in laravel?

Comment: If there is something you don't understand, I can make an edit and explain the issue again.

Comment: Is this currently impossible in Laravel?